# Browser keeps downloading php instead of executing it

Tags: nginx, php

First of all, I know this question has been duplicated about a thousand times but I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a week and I'm still totally lost.

Here's the server block in question

```
server {
    listen 4002;

    root /var/customer-sites/bellside7/wordpress;
    index index.php;
    server_name 192.241.151.113;

    location / {
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
            allow all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

So like I said, instead of executing PHP, my browser prompts me to download the page instead.

Now here's a really weird thing that happens too. If I stop the nginx process, this server block still works, and asks me to download the page, (but my other servers still go down). If I change the port to say 4003, now the page will do the same thing on port 4003 AND 4002. You can test this yourself now; If you go to the IP with port 4001, it still prompts to download the page even though I already changed the port to 4002. Now port 4002 and 4001 are doing the same thing even after I changed the port to 4002, even though there is no longer any configuration that tells anything to be served on 4001. It's like the server gets stuck in a state of limbo or something.

NOW THE REALLY MESSED UP PART

I tried shutting down the server, like totally turning off the computer. And it still serves a page and asks me to download it on port 4001 and 4002. My other servers still go down though. While the server was turned off I was still even able to access the page from any other computer, still with the same problem.

edit:

`sudo netstat -planet` output:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          59947       19324/nginx     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          9593        689/vsftpd      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          14617       1470/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          59948       19324/nginx     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          13058       1062/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          64487       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          13057       1062/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      106        36534       8326/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      110        14188       1347/memcached  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41233         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65677       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41253         ESTABLISHED 0          64952       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41287         ESTABLISHED 0          65029       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41250         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65687       20567/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41289         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65034       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41280         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65004       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41234         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65679       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41283         ESTABLISHED 0          65014       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41290         ESTABLISHED 0          65038       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41283         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65013       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41280         ESTABLISHED 0          65005       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41251         ESTABLISHED 0          64948       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41281         ESTABLISHED 0          65008       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41235         ESTABLISHED 0          65682       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41232         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65675       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41233         ESTABLISHED 0          65678       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41252         ESTABLISHED 0          64950       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41250         ESTABLISHED 0          64946       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41253         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65690       20567/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41249         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65686       20567/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41252         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65689       20567/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41251         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65688       20567/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41287         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65028       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41231         ESTABLISHED 0          65674       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41249         ESTABLISHED 0          64944       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41232         ESTABLISHED 0          65676       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41281         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65007       20539/node      
tcp        0   5348 192.241.151.113:22      50.141.211.238:62814        ESTABLISHED 0          65031       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41234         ESTABLISHED 0          65680       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41291         ESTABLISHED 0          65041       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41279         ESTABLISHED 0          65002       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41282         ESTABLISHED 0          65011       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41231         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65673       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41279         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65001       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41288         ESTABLISHED 0          65032       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41291         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65040       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         127.0.0.1:41289         ESTABLISHED 0          65035       20307/mongod    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41290         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65037       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41235         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65681       20539/node      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41282         127.0.0.1:27017         ESTABLISHED 0          65010       20539/node      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          59949       19324/nginx     
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          65691       20567/node      
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          14618       1470/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::3002                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          64880       20539/node
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `sudo netstat -planet4 | grep 4001` (and other ports) **AFTER** you shut down the server?

Comment: @rishta That command has no output at all. But also I was able to confirm that my browser isnt just caching the page because I tried going to it on a different computer that has never visited this ip before and it still does it (while the server was shut down even).

Comment: Try `sudo netstat -planet` (drop the 4, which says "`only show ipv4`") with and without `grep`. Hmmm this is cloud hosted, so you may need someone else's help :)

Comment: @rishta edited post

Comment: @rishta It's a VPS from DigitalOcean. But I am so confused as to what's going on here. My other nginx server blocks work fine, but those aren't using PHP. As soon as I added one with PHP all this started happening.

Comment: OK edit the post again, remove sshd entry ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close because you say that the computer works when it's turned off. That suggests your understanding is fundamentally flawed. If this is incorrect please reply below.

Comment: @Tim I'm not saying that is what's happening. I was simply describing what I see. The page is still accessible when the server is turned off. That is a fact that I have observed. I'm not saying it makes any sense, because it doesn't.

Comment: @Tim So yes that statement is fundamentally flawed. So it must mean that there is something going on with my VPS provider.

Comment: Are you using the correct IP address?

Answer (score 0):

It is downloading because that is the default behavior of nginx when it doesn't understand the file type.

My bet is php-fpm is not running or the socket is incorrect. From your listening output, it appears PHP is running on 127.0.0.1:9000 and not the UNIX socket.